# How to Autofill forms in WKWebView Using User Defaults or JavaScript

Tags: swift, swift3, wkwebview, autofill, userdefaults

Hello Swift Developers!.
I am new to swift programming and need little help.

I am developing a very simple app, that should simply load the web using `WkWebView` and **autofill** the shipping form it have in on of its page.

I have successfully managed to fetch the page in webView(`WkWebView`).
First it loads this url https://www.adidas.com/us, after selecting the item in to cart it gets to this delivery page https://www.adidas.com/us/delivery where we have to fill [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNDbJ.png) form. before this, no login information needed.

I am trying to make it done with both `UIWebView` and `WkWebView` but to no avail, here's my code, `UIWebView` part is commented.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var uiWebView: UIWebView!

var webView: WKWebView!
let url: String = "https://www.adidas.com/us/delivery"
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //WKWebView programatically so it can run below iOS 11
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
    
    if let safeUrl = URL(string: url){
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: safeUrl)
        webView.load(request)
        
    }
    
    //        uiWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL) as URLRequest)
    //        let result = uiWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.title")
    //        print("result is: \(result!)")
  
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('di-id-cab9a55c-9d253ce3').value = 'Hello'") { (result, error) in
            print(result) //This will Print Hello
        }

    
}



//    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
//
//        let email = defaults.string(forKey: "EMAIL")
//        let password = defaults.string(forKey: "Pass")
//
//        let fillForm = "document.getElementById('f_707d6a95-3ef9-4b76-a162-9361b4ef7d4d').value = \(password)"
//        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: fillForm)
//    }
```

}

And [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9K85.png) the screenshot of inspect element of `First Name` field.

After this I would use user default for autofill data. that step I know how to do just stuck here!

Can I have any helpful code snippet or suggestion please? I am really stuck at this point!
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you site uses vue.js , javascript updates will not reflect on data. Also the id will change randomly so can't use id.Are u able to solve this? I am

Comment: I am not able to solve this, How you did?

Answer (score 2):

First: stop using `UIWebView` since it's deprecated from one side and stop supporting by AppStore from Dec 2020.

You should set `navigationDelegate` to you WKWebView and set your values to the fields on `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` when the page is loaded e.g.:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    ...
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    ...
}

extension ViewController : WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Set a delay for dynamic pages
        //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            let fillForm = "document.getElementsByName('firstName')[0].value = 'My Name'"
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(fillForm, completionHandler: nil)
        //}
}
```

Comment: Hi @iUrii thanks for giving me some direction, When would this method get trigger

Comment: I have implemented delegate method with print(#function) statement in it but it is not getting triggered in the all procedure, can you please tell when it would get triggered?

Comment: Okay its getting triggered now, but no magic of autofilling.

Comment: @AafaqAhmed If your page is built dynamically you can make a delay or write a code to check that inputs are available - see my updated sample.

Comment: Thank you for doing me one step further, I have checked this and delays the time already. but Its not working!, But I know I am too close to the solution, your little more consideration may solve my problem. I have checked your updated sample it is identical to my own solution. but again appreciation.

Comment: this javascript is working perfect in chrome but not in swift code.

Comment: @AafaqAhmed hm... I've checked with delay in 2 secs on https://www.adidas.com/us/delivery and it works

Comment: when I use url https://www.adidas.com/us/delivery its working perfectly, but when I go to this page from this https://www.adidas.com/us after a lot of navigations (:didFinish:) method don't get trigger. Do you Know how we can solve this issue please?

Comment: Thank you again for you support, now this little issue of navigating left, every other thing is done.